# onConfigurationChanged is not getting called any time in android

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-orientation

I have create sample program to test Orientation. If portrait mode and I tilt the phone the other way round I want my sample app to reversePortrait. After reading lot of questions on this - Figured we need to need use:

```
   onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
```

I was trying out the following:

```
    @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    Configuration c = getResources().getConfiguration();

    Log.e("Config",""+c);

    if (c.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) 
    {
        // portrait

        Log.e("On Config Change","portrait");

    } 
    else if (c.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
    {
        // landscape
        Log.e("On Config Change","LANDSCAPE");

    }
}
```

manifest.xml

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

tried even this

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screensize"
```

Strange I am not getting logs inside OnConfigurationChange method.

Not sure. What is the problem here?

I am using minimum api 8 to target Api 18.

Can somebody help me out with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is screen orientation enabled on your device?

Comment: How do you do reversed portrait? Can you post the code where you force it to be in reverse portrait mode. Do you use `setRequestedOrientation` function to do it? If yes then once you use use this function, you're not candidate to receive orientation changes.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski - Yes. It is enabled.

Answer (score 4):

I had a same issue after changing target API to 19(4.4 kitkat)
You need to add layoutDirection attribute for targeting higher than version 17.

my attribute looks like:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|layoutDirection"
```

The key is to add 'layoutDirection'

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this problem, and fixed it with this weird little trick.

Set your `screenOrientation` in your manifest, like so:

```
android:screenOrientation="sensor"
```

That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code  is no problem 
Modify your manifest.xml
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
I hope it can help you

Comment: The manifest change you are asking me to put is accepted for Api more that 12. I 
am currently targeting Api 8 and more