# onConfigurationChanged is not getting triggered

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation, android-orientation, onconfigurationchanged

I have to detect when the configuration has changed. I have put the configChanges conditions in the manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name=".WorkoutActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
    </activity>
```

There are no setRequestedOrientation in the activity or in any fragment. Here is the code for configuration change:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Toast.makeText(this, "activity rotated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the rotation not being detected was because I had set the device rotation to portrait (canceled autorotate) on my mobile phone. This prevented my app from rotating. Found the answer here:
[onConfigurationChanged not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620033/onconfigurationchanged-not-getting-called)

The way to override this preference set by the user is to add the following code to the manifest as answered here: [onConfigurationChanged is not getting called any time in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960525/onconfigurationchanged-is-not-getting-called-any-time-in-android)

```
android:screenOrientation="sensor"
```

Now the app rotates based on the sensor input and onConfigurationChanged is triggered. I hope this answer helps others get rid of this potential bug.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">